# Which usb driver is called in order to transfer data?

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver

I would like to change the behaviour of one of my USB flash drive by editing its driver, but i can't find which driver is called.

I searched and i found that the drivers/usb/storage/transport.c is responsible for some exchanges beetween the host and the device (configuration), but i want to find the driver that sends URB whith data.

Is there any way to find that?

Thank you

Luis

Comment: What is a USB key? Try using `ftrace` to see what gets called.

Comment: Sorry, it's the litteral translation from my language.I meant USB flash drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched and i found that it's the function usb_stor_bulk_transfer_sglist in transport.c that perform a data transfer for a USB flash drive

In fact, it uses URB with sglist of address